# Word for email that renders across all devices?

Tags: single-word-requests, email

It's important for our emails to render without issues across all supported email clients and devices: Outlook, Yahoo, Comcast, Gmail, iPhone, Android, tablets, etc.

The only word I can think of is "bulletproof" ("bulletproof email", "bulletproof email components") but I'm not sure if that's the correct technical term:

> We have a focus on developing ("bulletproof") emails- our emails render on any device or email client.

Is there a widely-used term to describe an email that renders well across all clients and devices?

Comment: You might want to ask this on the UX stack exchange site - https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: fwiw "bulletproof" is what I would opt for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The industry standard term is **responsive**.

From [A List Apart](https://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design):

> Recently, an emergent discipline called *“responsive architecture”* has begun asking how physical spaces can respond to the presence of people passing through them.
>
> Rather than tailoring disconnected designs to each of an ever-increasing number of web devices, we can treat them as facets of the same experience. We can design for an optimal viewing experience, but embed standards-based technologies into our designs to make them not only more flexible, but more adaptive to the media that renders them. In short, we need to practice *responsive web design*.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design):

> **Responsive web design (RWD)** is an approach to web design which makes web pages render well on a variety of devices and window or screen sizes. Recent work also considers the viewer proximity as part of the viewing context as an extension for RWD. Content, design and performance are necessary across all devices to ensure usability and satisfaction.